# How to map multiple Subject in an object literal to an object literal of corresponding Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am working on a class in Angular and want to share a bunch of states belong to that class. So I make a bunch of `BehaviorSubject`

```
private subjects = {
    a : new BehaviorSubject<A>(this.a),
    b : new BehaviorSubject<B>(this.b),
    c : new BehaviorSubject<C>(this.c),
    d : new BehaviorSubject<D>(this.d),
    e : new BehaviorSubject<E>(this.e),
}
```

To prevent leaking the `Observer` side of the subjects and only expose the `Observable` side, I make the subjects private and expose with observables:

```
observables = {
    a : this.subjects.a.pipe(share()),
    b : this.subjects.b.pipe(share()),
    c : this.subjects.c.pipe(share()),
    d : this.subjects.d.pipe(share()),
    e : this.subjects.e.pipe(share()),
}
```

I think the observables should be able to be generated from the subjects so that when I want to add more subjects, I don't need to modify the observables manually. Something like:

```
observables = (()=>{
    let observables : {[Property in keyof typeof this.subjects]:Observable} = {}
    for(let key in this.subjects)
    {
        observables[key] = this.subjects[key as keyof typeof this.subjects].pipe(share())
    }
    return observables;
})();
```

But here `Observable` and `share` do not know their generic type. How can I make this work or if there is better pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware you don't need to `share` the `BehaviorSubject` observable as it is already hot via the `BehaviorSubject`.

You can solve the generic typing issues by using [Mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```
const subjects = {
  a: new BehaviorSubject<number>(1),
  b: new BehaviorSubject<string>('foo'),
  c: new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false),
};

// utility type to convert BehaviorSubject<T> to Observable<T> 
// (can be inlined below instead)
type BehaviorSubjectToObservable<T> = 
  T extends BehaviorSubject<infer U> ? Observable<U> : never;

// create appropriate type for resulting object which has the same keys
// but maps to Observable<T>
// this ensures correct typing within the reduce
type Observables<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: BehaviorSubjectToObservable<T[P]>;
};

// transform the object
const observables = Object.entries(subjects).reduce(
  (acc, [key, subject]) => ({ ...acc, ...{ [key]: subject.asObservable() } }),
  {} as Observables<typeof subjects>,
);

// typeof observables.a = Observable<number>
// typeof observables.b = Observable<string>
// typeof observables.c = Observable<boolean>
```